# Ajax xhr.upload.onprogress printing wrong values for loaded and total

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, post

Im trying to build a webform to upload files to my s3 bucket via the AWS lamda and the apigateway services.
The upload is working fine and I need a progress bar to be added to the form to show the user the status and progress of their upload.

The methodology uses Ajax and a post request.

The script I have written that tries to use a progress bar is shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ObjectUploadBtnId").click(function() {
    /*===============================================================*/
    /*===============================================================*/
    /* Copy and paste these next 23 lines for each file you need to upload    */
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://zbnr38m2rg.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/presignedurl',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      data: JSON.stringify({
        "BucketName": "BucketNAME",
        "methodType": "POST",
        "FileName": $('#FileNameId').val()
      }, ),
      dataType: "json",
      xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
          if (e.lengthComputable) {
            console.log(e.loaded, e.total)
            var percentComplete = e.loaded / e.total;
            console.log(percentComplete);
            $('#status').html('<b> Uploading -> ' + (Math.round(percentComplete * 100)) + '% </b>');
          }
        }
        return xhr;
      },
      //beforeSend: function(){ $( '#loader' ).show();},
      success: function(res) {
        uploadFile(res, res.url);
      },
      error: function(e) {
        $("#urlTextId").html("Failed: Unable to Get Signed Upload Url" + e.responseText);
        $("#SignedUrlId").html("");
        $("#div-obj-holderId").show();
      },
      complete: function() {
        $('#loader').hide();
      }
    });
    /*===============================================================*/
    /*===============================================================*/


  });
});
```

The problem
The progress bar is going straight to 100% even for very large files. I have tried to diagnose the problem further and it seems as though the variables `e.loaded` `e.total` are equivalent to each other right at the start of the upload. Secondly, the values are not consistent with the actual size of the file I am trying to upload.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of the problem and how to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: you can't use JSON for file uploads, you have to use `FormData`.

Comment: You can't get the file contents with `.val()`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload/2320097#2320097 for how to do file uploads with AJAX. You can add the progress code to that.